# Which Node Is Popped First in Priority Queue if Two Are Equal Weight

Tags: python, search, stack, nodes, priority-queue

I am working with this `GraphSearch` psuedo-code algorithm to find the shortest path to a goal from a starting position:

```
function GRAPH-SEARCH(problem,fringe,strategy) return a solution, or failure
   closed <-- an empty set
   fringe <-- INSERT(MAKE-NODE(INITIAL-STATE[problem]),fringe)
   loop do
      if fringe is empty then return failure
      node <-- REMOVE-FRONT(fringe,strategy)
      if STATE[node] is not in closed then
         add STATE[node] to closed
         for child-node in EXPAND(STATE[node],problem) do
            fringe <-- INSERT(child-node,fringe)
         end
   end
```

I am implementing the `A*` stretegy of searching for a goal from a starting position. `A*` search makes use of the formula:

f(n) = g(n) + h(n)

where g(n) is the cost to get to the current `child-node`, h(n) is the heuristic value to get to the goal (we are assuming the heuristic determined **is admissable**), and f(n) is the combined value we assign to that `node` in the `fringe`.

In `A*` search, a `PriorityQueue` is used to determine which `child-node` to `pop()` next to test for the goal state and/or expand to more children, which in this case is the `child-node` with the lowest value.

Here is my question:

I have a current `PriorityQueue` as follows:

```
     S -> B = 1 + 3 = 4  // The cost to B + the heuristic value to goal
     S -> A = 1 + 3 = 4  // The cost to A + the heuristic value to goal
          S = 0 + 0 = 0  // Has been popped & expanded
```

Where `S` is the starting position, and `A` and `B` are child nodes.
There are two paths that are assigned the next lowest value 4, so which path does a `PriorityQueue` `pop()` next?

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out?

Comment: I don't have an implementation set up, I am working with psuedo-code and scratch paper. I was just wondering if someone could answer so I know which one to do if it appears on a test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have learned that by nature of a `PriorityQueue`, if the priority values of the next items are equal, then the structure is simply treated as a `Queue`.

In this case that means that since `S -> A = 1 + 3 = 4` was the first in, it will be the first out.

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.PriorityQueue;
class HelloWorld {

```
static class pair implements Comparable<pair>
{
    int ver;
    int wt;
    
    
    pair(int i, int j)
    {
        this.ver = i ;
        this.wt = j;
      
    }
    
    public int compareTo(pair p)
    {
        return this.wt - p.wt;
    }
    
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PriorityQueue<pair> pq = new PriorityQueue<pair>();

    pq.offer(new pair(0,2));
    pq.offer(new pair(1,4));
    pq.offer(new pair(2,2));
    
    pair p = pq.poll();
    System.out.println("this pop" + p.ver);

}
```

}

*****OUTPUT******
this pop0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).